# How to make JavaFX app auto resize for different screen resolutions

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm developing a JavaFX application but I don't know how to make it auto adjustable across different screens. As I'm developing on laptop having resolution (1920 x 1080), everything is going ok here, but when I move the app to my another laptop having resolution (1366 x 768), the app view becomes large enough to be fit on the screen. As given in the following pictures:

With 1920 x 1080 : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iXJ86VNaitU_csM4nuudesAJJvLvg180/view?usp=sharing

With 1366 x 768 :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_1igAmvyTnqdRXYMjcI9--7p8mNp3qSj/view?usp=sharing

Kindly help me out of this problem, as my software is only getting delayed of this tiny bug.

Comment: This is most likely due to you using Layout nodes incorrectly.

Comment: You are going to have to post your FXML or node Structure.

Comment: If you’re using AnchorPanes to create “absolute” layouts, replace that with other layouts, like BorderPane and GridPane.  Specifying exact positions and sizes of nodes is not compatible with running in different resolutions.  This, in fact, is one of the reasons layouts exist.

Comment: @sedrick the code is too lengthy to be posted here

Comment: @VGR sir my project has atleast 15 to 20 fxml files using anchorpane, so its' almost impossible for me to convert them all to borderpane. Isn't there any way to adjust the application's resolution according to the current screen's resolution?

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but I don’t think there is an alternative.  It may seem like a lot of work, but at least you only have to do it once for each Scene.  The additional benefit is that you will learn how to create user interfaces correctly, and you won’t need to do this ever again.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48351764/scaling-aligning-elements-in-a-scene-when-the-window-is-being-resized/48352225#48352225 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464044/javafx-move-element-on-window-stage-resize/54464785#54464785 can help.

Comment: There are two issues here. One issue is the inner components which I believe have been discussed. The other issue is the screen size, if your opening the main stage with a constant width and hight that's trouble. You want to take a look at the Scren class. You can get the current screen size and set the stage to a constant ratio based on he size. For example 3/4 ot height and width of the current screen size.

Answer (score -1):

stage.setMinHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getHeight()); stage.setMinWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getBounds().getWidth());

Comment: Please, provide any explanation what is the root cause for the original problem, and how does your solution address it. Code-only answers provide solutions, but original question's author can't learn from it.